# Stack Exchange network profile doesn't show top answers

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-exchange

You can see my [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522602/balintpekker) I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612979/trouble-installing-pecl-apd-on-ubuntu/24690411#24690411) accepted with a score of 6.

[image]

I also have a question with a score of 25. Both the answer and the question has more than 5 votes however my [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4311719/balintpekker) shows only the question listed as "score of 5 or more".

[image]

I also synced Stack Exchange with Stack Overflow but the Top Answers section doesn't updated.

**EDIT:** The answer has more than 5 score like months ago.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I thought that the Top Questions/Answers section applies to the site on which you are viewing your profile. So the Stack Exchange would show your Top Questions/Answers for the Stack Exchange site, on which you can't post, so there would be none.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Then how is that my SO question is there, but my SO answer isn't?

Comment: Maybe the `[php]` tag is filtered out? *Runs away*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why would it be?

Comment: Doesn't it take something like up to 24 hours to update?

Comment: @BrianJ Maybe, but in this case the answer has more than 5 answers like months ago.

Comment: @balintpekker I didn't realize that.  I'd add that into the question body,

Comment: @balintpekker: Yikes, why _wouldn't_ it be? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well that's a point too :) I'm just sayin' why would only the `[php]` tag filtered out? Should I ask what other tags are filtered out too?:)